# Change size of all items from a Grid

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, uielement, win-universal-app

I try to change the width of all Items in several grids, which are in a grid, too. The items are Textboxes, CheckBoxes, Sliders, Buttons etc.

Here are my solution approaches:

```
foreach (Control itemGrid in mainGrid.Children)
            {
                if (itemGrid.GetType() == typeof(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid));
                {
                    foreach (UIElement item in itemGrid.Children)
                        item.Width = 100;
                }  
            }
```

Here is an example, to understand what I mean.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="885" Margin="1186,226,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="598" Background="Black">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="74,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="433" Background="#FF727272">
                <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="71" Width="143"/>
                <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="283,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="71" Width="143"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,131,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="More Items .." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="351" Height="79" FontSize="48"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="240" Margin="74,587,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="433" Background="#FF727272">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,81,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="More Items .." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="351" Height="79" FontSize="48"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="217" Margin="74,314,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="433" Background="#FF727272">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,81,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="More Items .." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="351" Height="79" FontSize="48"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

[image: e.x]

Comment: What is item1 in your code?

Comment: Ohh, yes. It was a mistake. I will correct this.

Comment: OK, now please explain what's not working with your current approach?

Comment: There are serval exeptions and itemGrid hasn't a namespace for "Children".

Comment: What is the mainGrid? It's not in your XAML.

Comment: The XAML Code is only an example. But the mainGrid could complie with the first grid(black) of the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, for the answers. I've found a solution for the problem.

```
IEnumerable<Grid> grids = mainGrid.Children.OfType<Grid>();
            foreach (Grid itemGrid in grids)
            {
                IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> items = itemGrid.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>();
                foreach (FrameworkElement item in items)
                    {
                        item.Width = 100;
                    }       
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the VisualTreeHelper:

```
  VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount()
  VisualTreeHelper.GetChild()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper%28v=win.10%29.aspx